# read csv to pandas retaining values as it is

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read a csv and get it into a dataframe but I want to retain the values of columns.

For eg. my first column has values like `001234`, `003462` in the csv file but the dataframe interprets it as `1234`, `3462`, etc. How do I retain the '00' at the front?

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, dtype=str)
```